# Record Opens Directly to Visualforce Section Not Top of Page

Tags: visualforce

When adding the Visualforce section to our page layout, it brings the user directly to this section when clicking into a record. How do we open the record to the top of the page?

Comment: Sara, can you add some more details to your question, a screenshot would be much better

Comment: I will but just to clarify its like I click on a record and new page automatically scroll down to input field. I dont want to get it scrolled.